# setting values in a data frame according to another data frame

Tags: r

i have a small (2k) dataset. each row has its own unique id under "id" column. 
from another software i get a subset of this data with values only to some rows. 
i now need to find a way to insert each value to correct id and set NA in the other values. 
here is a simple example:

```
data = data.frame(id =1:10, b= rep(c("boy", "girl"), each = 5))
sub_data = data frame(id = c(1,4,7,8), value = c( 0.1,0.3,0.15,0.9))
```

and the answer should look like:

```
final_data = data.frame(id =1:10, b= rep(c("boy", "girl"), each = 5), values = c(0.1, "NA", "NA", 0.3, "NA", "NA", 0.15, 0.9, "NA", "NA"))
```

thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `merge`

```
 merge(data, sub_data, all.x=TRUE)
```

Comment: thank you, 
someone posted that this questions is a duplicate and linked a similar question. 

thanks for helping!

Comment: i tried. it says i have to wait before accepting an answer.

Comment: @isomitzi  No problem.  Thank you!